# How to reduce INDEPENDENT SET to INDEPENDENT SET SIZE?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np-complete

Suppose you are given a polynomial-time algorithm for the following problem related to INDEPENDENT SET:

> INDEPENDENT SET VALUE
>
> Input: An undirected graph $G$.
>
> Output:The size of the largest independent set in G (but not the set itself).

Show how you can use this algorithm to solve the INDEPENDENT SET problem in polynomial time: given a graph $G$, return an independent set which is as large as possible.

Any help would be really appreciated. I am pretty lost in this question

Comment: @MJD Why are y'all shouting?

Comment: Please reduce your use of caps!!!

Comment: It is very common in the literature to write the names of formal problems in all-caps.

Comment: @rschwieb and Gugg: An independent set is a set of vertices with no edges among them. INDEPENDENT SET is the problem of finding an independent set of maximum size in a given graph.  It make sense to discuss the time complexity of the latter, but not the former.

Comment: Crossposted [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/how-to-reduce-independent-set-to-independent-set-size).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose you run INDEPENDENT SET VALUE on $G$ and get $n$. Then you delete a vertex from $G$ to get $G'$ and run INDEPENDENT SET VALUE on $G'$.  What are the possible results?  What might you learn from each of the possible results?